# Refraction and diffraction

Tags: optics, refraction, diffraction, huygens-principle

Huygens principle. can we accordingly define refraction to be diffraction from an infinitesimal length slit?

According to Huygens principle,  sticking to classical physics terms. as long as slit length is at most a wavelength,  spherical form of waves is maintained. If we look at propagation inside a homogeneous medium the shape of waveforms is maintained and we can claim "mono-refraction".

So is diffraction actually a mono-refraction through an infinitesimal length of slit?

As a thought experiment...

Comment: Only the ideal spherical, and its limit as $radius \to \infty$ , the planar wave, would maintain its shape in an homogeneous medium. An arbitrary waveform will distort its shape while propagating. So I do not know what you mean by mono-refraction in general.

Comment: monochromatic plane wave in homogeneous medium

Comment: "define refraction to be diffraction from an infinitesimal length slit," Refraction in the books I have studied needs a variable index medium, you have just stated that the medium be homogeneous; what kind of refraction are you talking about?

Comment: what i am visualizing is a wavefront impacting a "virtual screen" i.e. a perpendicular plane to propagation continuously to the same material, call it "zero angle refraction" or "monotefraction".

Comment: you are using words that, to the extent I understand them, I cannot associate with concepts I thought I knew somwhat.

Comment: then 2 media with same $n$. now do you understand?